# Join two spark Dataframe using the nested column and update one of the columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on some requirement in which I am getting one small table in from of CSV file as follow:

```
root
 |-- ACCT_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SUBID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- MCODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NewClosedDate: timestamp (nullable = true
```

We also have a very big external hive table in form of Avro which is stored in HDFS as follow:

```
root
-- accountlinks: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- account: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- acctno: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- subid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- openeddate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- closeddate: string (nullable = true)
```

Now, the requirement is to look up the the external hive table based on the three columns from the csv file : `ACCT_NO - SUBID - MCODE`. If it matches, updates the `accountlinks.account.closeddate` with `NewClosedDate` from CSV file.

I have already written the following code to explode the required columns and join it with the small table but I am not really sure how to update the closeddate field ( this is currently null for all account holders) with NewClosedDate because closeddate is a nested column and I  cannot easily use withColumn to populate it. In addition to that  the schema and column names cannot be changed as these files are linked to some external hive table.

```
 val df = spark.sql("select * from db.table where archive='201711'")

val ExtractedColumn = df 
.coalesce(150)
.withColumn("ACCT_NO", explode($"accountlinks.account.acctno"))
.withColumn("SUBID", explode($"accountlinks.account.acctsubid"))
.withColumn("MCODE", explode($"C.mcode"))

val ReferenceData = spark.read.format("csv")
.option("header","true")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.load("file.csv")

val FinalData = ExtractedColumn.join(ReferenceData, Seq("ACCT_NO","SUBID","MCODE") , "left")
```

Comment: You are trying to update external table you can not do it .  you have to make new copy of data and replace it with external location and update  stats ( Msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>)

Comment: Yes I know that. Make a new copy or even overwrite it could solve that. But before that, I need to populate the accountlinks.account.closeddate with NewClosedDate from csv file. This is the challenge for me now.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to explode the `accountlinks` array and then join the 2 dataframes like this:

```
val explodedDF = df.withColumn("account", explode($"accountlinks"))
val joinCondition = $"ACCT_NO" === $"account.acctno" && $"SUBID" === $"account.subid" && $"MCODE" === $"account.mcode"
val joinDF  = explodedDF.join(ReferenceData, joinCondition, "left")
```

Now you can update the `account` struct column like below, and collect list to get back the array structure:

```
val FinalData = joinDF.withColumn("account", 
                                  struct($"account.acctno", $"account.subid", $"account.mcode", 
                                         $"account.openeddate", $"NewClosedDate".alias("closeddate")
                                        )
                                 )
                        .groupBy().agg(collect_list($"account").alias("accountlinks"))
```

The idea is to create a new struct with all the fields from  `account` except `closedate` that you get from `NewCloseDate` column.

If the struct contains many fields you can use a for-comprehension to get all the fields except the close date to prevent typing them all.

Comment: You solution works, but the only thing is that there are multiple fields outside accountlinks. I tried to add them using withColumn but they are not shown. Do I have to put them in groupBy() ?

Comment: val FinalData = joinDF
.withColumn("fileno", $"fileno")
.withColumn("addresses", $"addresses")
.withColumn("accountlinks",
                                  struct(struct($"account.account.acctno", $"account.account.acctsubid", $"account.account.mbrcode",
                                         $"account.account.openeddate", $"NewClosedDate".alias("closeddate")
                                        ).as("account")
   
                                 ))

.withColumn("bans", $"bans")
                                 .groupBy("*").agg(collect_list($"account").alias("accountlinks"))

Comment: If the only array you want to update is `accountlinks` then use the above solution and add the other columns in the `groupBy`.