# How to update a nested column in spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, nested

I have the following nested table and trying to replace the closeddate column with NewClosedDate :

```
root
--field1 : string (nullable = true)
--field2 : string (nullable = true)
--field100 : string (nullable = true)
-- accountlinks1 : array (nullable = true)
-- accountlinks2 : array (nullable = true)
-- accountlinks3 : array (nullable = true)
-- accountlinks100: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- account: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- acctno: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- subid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- openeddate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- closeddate: string (nullable = true)
-- NewClosedDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

There are many fields(String and Array) inside root, many structs inside each array as well as many fields inside each struct.  So I was wondering  how I can replace `closeddate` field with `NewClosedDate` using Spark/DataFrame. The NewClosedDate field gets generated after joining two DFs.

Comment: `closeddate` is in array, `NewClosedDate` is outer field. So, what element in array you want to replace `closeddate` with `NewClosedDate` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to put the outer field (NewClosedDate) inside the array and remove closeddate

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. `NewClosedDate` is one value but `closeddate` is in array so it has multiple value. What is your replace rule ?

Comment: please look at this question, this is exactly what I am trying to do but am struggling to replace NewclosedDate with old one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710866/join-two-spark-dataframe-using-the-nested-column-and-update-one-of-the-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a couple of ways - using dataset and case class or an UDF.

Here is how using a case class,

```
    case class Account(accountNo:String, subbed: String, var closeDate : Timestamp)

    case class MyTable(field1:String, field2  ......
    , accountlinks100 : Seq[Account], newCloseDate : Timestamp
    )

    val df = // read dataframe.as[MyTable]
    val updatedDf = df.map{ r : MyTable => 
    r.accountlinks100.forEach(a => a.closeDate = r.newCloseDate)
    r
    }
```

I used var to make the field updatable. If you don't like that then use val and copy the MyTable object into a new object with changed value of closeDate.